# Allow YouTube embeds

Tags: feature-request

[Some sites on the SE network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71234/add-chat-like-youtube-support-to-stack-exchange) allow direct embedding of YouTube videos now.

I propose German.SE be one of these sites.

Short video snippets can be excellent to illustrate  a point about a dialect, a way of pronunciation, and so on.

Comment: Finde ich eine großartige Idee! Bernd, bitte nicht die Antworten vorkauen, das verdirbt irgendwie die Lust zu kommentieren :/

Answer (score 10):

Yes - videos should be allowed.

---

Ja Videos sollten erlaubt sein.

Answer (score 1):

No - Videos should not be allowed.

---

Nein - Videos sollten nicht erlaubt sein.